# Unable to fetch docs ids in firebase firestore using NodeJS (Google cloud functions)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Need to fetch all the document ids present in the collection.

```
// get all users' id
    const allUserIds = [];

    db.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        console.log(querySnapshot._docs);
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            allUserIds.push(doc.id);
        });
    });
    console.log(allUserIds);
```

The list, allUserIds is getting empty in log.

Comment: The .then() method is registering a callback to a Promise. This means that that block of code will be executed when the data is retrieved, and usually it takes some times (milliseconds, but still it takes time). The console.log(allUserIds) will be executed before the forEach, printing an empty array in the logs

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[How to return the response from an asynchronous call](//stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/90527)"

Comment: See also "[How do I wait for a promise to finish before returning the variable of a function?](//stackoverflow.com/q/27759593/90527)"

Answer (score 2):

`get()` is asynchronous and returns a promise.  You will need to learn how promises work in JavaScript if you want to use Firestore effectively.  For now, put the console log inside the callback to see that the query works.

```
    db.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        console.log(querySnapshot._docs);
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            allUserIds.push(doc.id);
        });
        console.log(allUserIds);
    });
```

It will be up to you to understand JavaScript promises and use them correctly for your application - it is a general concept not unique to Firestore.

Comment: empty log. seems like query is not running

Comment: Have you tried using `catch` to trap any errors?  That's another important part of learning how promises work.  I suggest first following a tutorial to better learn how to program with promises before trying to learn Firestore.  Firestore works fine - your code has to deal with it correctly.